# Python 2.7: read a txt file, split and group a few column count from right

Tags: python-2.7, txt

Due to the txt file has some flaw, the .txt file need to split from the right. below is some part f the files. Notice that the first row has only 4 columns and the other row has 5 columns. **I want the data from the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th columns from the right**

```
5123 - SENTRAL REIT - SENTA.KL - [$SENT]
KIPT - 5280 - KIP REAL EST - KIPRA.KL - [$KIPR]
ALIT - 5269 - AL-SALAM REAL - ALSAA.KL - [$ALSA]
KLCC - 5235SS - KLCC PROP - KLCCA.KL - [$KLCC]
IGBgggREIT - 5227 - IGB RT - IGREA.KL - [$IGRE]
SUNEIT - 5176 - SUNWAY RT - SUNWA.KL - [$SUNW]
ALA78QAR - 5116 - AL-AQAR HEA RT - ALQAA.KL - [$ALQA]
```

I want the file to be saved in .csv and can be read by pandas later
The desired output is

```
Code,Company,RIC
5123,SENTRAL REIT,SENTA.KL 
5280,KIP REAL EST, KIPRA.KL
5269,AL-SALAM REAL,ALSAA.KL
5235SS,KLCC PROP,KLCCA.KL 
5227,IGB RT,IGREA.KL
5176,SUNWAY RT,SUNWA.KL
5116,AL-AQAR HEA RT,ALQAA.KL
```

My code is below

```
>>> with open('abc.txt', 'r') as reader:
>>>     [x for x in reader.read().strip().split(' - ') if x]
```

It returns a list and I unable to group the to the right column due to the flaw of the list (unequal columns in some rows if it is counted from left)

Please advise how to get the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :)

```
import pandas as pd

with open('abc.txt', 'r') as reader:
    data = [line.split(' - ')[-4:-1] for line in reader.readlines()]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Code', 'Company', 'RIC'], data=data)
df.to_csv('abc.csv', sep=',', index=0)
```

Comment: Thanks. It returns `TypeError: "delimiter" must be string, not unicode` when `df.to_csv('abc.csv', sep=',', index=0)`. I try with `encoding='utf-8'` but still same error

Comment: Strange. Can you save it like this?

    `df.to_csv('abc.csv')`